# Is there an efficient replacement to "lambda x: x"?

Tags: python, lambda

When calling a function that expects a function as parameter, sometimes I just want to return the identity function `lambda x:x`. This seems inefficient, since it needs a function call to just return x. Is there a more efficient built-in for that?

Comment: So... you want the identity function, but not a function call?

Comment: @Sören yes, I want to save the function call. Since in my use-case, this function is going to be called millions of times.

Comment: How can you save a function call of a function argument? Can you provide a [mre] to help demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Also, do you actually have proof that this is your bottleneck? *"Is there a more efficient"* - I doubt that calling `lambda x:x` is the cause for any efficiency problems...

Comment: Did you profile your script and determine that that was the bottleneck? If it's just a hunch, then don't bother; get hard numbers before you start optimizing anything (otherwise it's [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092)). Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) is a post about how to profile Python scripts.

Comment: If it's being called millions of times, you have a problem. What's going on here?

Comment: FWIW, calling a generic identity function a million times took less than a tenth of a second, 0.07 s

Comment: Anyway, I don't really see how a built-in function would take away the need for a function call. The python function itself will basically be two OP codes, a LOAD_FAST and a RETURN_VALUE. I suppose a function written in C that just returns the PyObject pointer would be faster, but if you are optimizing at this level, CPython probably isn't the language / implementation for you